# Fetch data manually using useReducer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to fetch data from server using `loadData()` not only on ComponentDidMount, but also after methods `onFiltersClear`, `onApplyFilters` and `onPageChange`. How could I do that? Do I need some custom data fetching hook here or there are other ways to do that?

```
import { Table } from "lpcnse-core-front";
import Filters from "./Filters/Filters";
import { styles } from "./checks.css";

const STATUSES_PARENT_ID = "2F24B71C-C70A-4980-9D45-E4134D38E9E0";

const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 20;

const INITIAL_PAGINATION = {
  pageNumber: 1,
  itemsPerPageCount: ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
  totalCount: 0,
  pageCount: 0
};

const INITIAL_FILTERS = {
  title: "",
  сontrolledObject: "",
  status: null
};

const initialState = {
  filters: INITIAL_FILTERS,
  checks: [],
  pagination: INITIAL_PAGINATION,
  selectedCheckId: null,
  statusList: []
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_DATA_PENDING":
      return {
        ...state,
        checks: []
      };
    case "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS":
      const { items, pageNumber, pageCount, totalCount } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        checks: items,
        pagination: {
          ...state.pagination,
          pageCount,
          totalCount,
          pageNumber
        }
      };
    case "FETCH_DATA_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        checks: [],
        pagination: INITIAL_PAGINATION
      };
    case "SET_FILTER_INPUT":
      return {
        ...state,
        filters: {
          ...state.filters,
          ...action.payload
        }
      };
    case "SET_FILTER_STATE":
      const { status } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        filters: {
          ...state.filters,
          status
        }
      };
    case "CLEAR_FILTERS":
      return {
        ...state,
        filters: INITIAL_FILTERS
      };
    case "SET_PAGE_NUMBER":
      return {
        ...state,
        pagination: {
          ...state.pagination,
          pageNumber
        }
      };
    case "RESET_PAGINATION":
      return {
        ...state,
        pagination: INITIAL_PAGINATION
      };
    case "FETCH_STATUSES_SUCCESS":
      const { statusList } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        statusList
      };
    case "FETCH_STATUSES_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        statusList: []
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

export const Checks = props => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const {
    checks,
    pagination: { pageCount, pageNumber },
    filters,
    filters: { title, сontrolledObject, status },
    selectedCheckId,
    statusList
  } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
    loadStatusList();
  }, []);

  const loadData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await props.api.check.getChecks({
        filters: {
          title,
          сontrolledObject,
          status
        },
        pageNumber,
        maxRowCount: ITEMS_PER_PAGE
      });

      const { items, pageNumber, pageCount, totalCount } = response.data;
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
        payload: {
          pageNumber,
          pageCount,
          totalCount,
          items: items || []
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_DATA_ERROR"
      });
    }
  };

  const loadStatusList = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await props.api.type.getStatuses({
        parentId: STATUSES_PARENT_ID
      });
      const { items } = response.data;
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_STATUSES_SUCCESS",
        payload: {
          statusList: items || []
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_STATUSES_ERROR"
      });
    }
  };

  const onFilterInputChange = e => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_FILTER_INPUT",
      payload: {
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  const onFilterStatusChange = e => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_FILTER_STATE",
      payload: {
        status
      }
    });
  };

  const onFiltersClear = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CLEAR_FILTERS"
    });

    // loadData
  };

  const onApplyFilters = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "RESET_PAGINATION"
    });

    // loadData
  };

  const onPageChange = data => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_PAGE_NUMBER",
      payload: {
        pageNumber: data.selected + 1
      }
    });

    // loadData
  };

  const onSort = () => {};

  const onOpenUserCard = () => {};

  const columns = [
    //some columns
  ];

  return (
    <div className="checks">
      <Filters
        onFilterInputChange={onFilterInputChange}
        onFilterStatusChange={onFilterStatusChange}
        onApplyFilters={onApplyFilters}
        onClear={onFiltersClear}
        filters={filters}
        statusList={statusList}
      />
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        data={checks}
        onSort={onSort}
        paginated={true}
        onPageChange={onPageChange}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        forcePage={pageNumber}
        selectedItemId={selectedCheckId}
      />

      <style jsx>{styles}</style>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to making the loading functions react to filter changes is to add filters to the `useEffect()` dependency list.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  loadData();
  loadStatusList();
}, [filters, pageNumber]);
```

although I don't see `loadStatusList()` depending on filters, so recommendation is to separate the two async calls into their own effects

```js
useEffect(() => {
  loadData();
}, [filters, pageNumber]);

useEffect(() => {
  loadStatusList();
}, []);
```

Lastly, the load* functions are getting re-created on every render, so you can move them into the respective effects, or wrap them in `useCallback()`, or move them outside the component (but then you would have to pass all params instead of using closure).

```js
useEffect(() => {

  const loadData = async () => {
    ...
  });

  loadData();
}, [filters]);

useEffect(() => {

  const loadStatusList = async () => {
    ...
  });

  loadStatusList();
}, []);
```

---

I can see from comments that you haven't connected the events (button clicks) and the state changes.

1. Side effects, particularly async ones ***must*** be wrapped in a `useEffect()`.
2. `useEffects` are triggered when ***only*** state changes (or special case of empty dependency list which === onMount).
3. Since you can only run effects on state change, you must make the event (button click) change some state, then use that state in the `useEffect()` dependency list as a trigger.

So, following the onFilterInputChange event

```
onFilterInputChange 
-> dispatch(SET_FILTER_INPUT) 
-> reducer sets new value for filters
-> effect has filters as dependency, so it runs
-> loadData called with new filters as parameter
-> on response dispatch(FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS) with new data
```

The only problem we might have is that `pagerNumber` is an input and an output of the effect, so may get a feedback loop when updating.

To be safe we can add a state variable that controls fetching

```
const initialState = {
  filters: INITIAL_FILTERS,
  checks: [],
  pagination: INITIAL_PAGINATION,
  selectedCheckId: null,
  statusList: [],
  doFetch: true    // initially true === do a fetch on mount
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case "FETCH_DATA_PENDING":
      return {
        ...state,
        checks: [],
        doFetch: true
      };    

    case "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS":
      const { items, pageNumber, pageCount, totalCount } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        checks: items,
        pagination: {
          ...state.pagination,
          pageCount,
          totalCount,
          pageNumber
        },
        doFetch: false
      };

    case "FETCH_DATA_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        checks: [],
        pagination: INITIAL_PAGINATION,
        doFetch: false
      };
    ...

  const onFilterInputChange = e => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_FILTER_INPUT",
      payload: {
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
    dispatch({type: "FETCH_DATA_PENDING" });
  };

  const onFilterStatusChange = e => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_FILTER_STATE",
      payload: {
        status
      }
    });
    dispatch({type: "FETCH_DATA_PENDING" });
  };

  const onFiltersClear = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CLEAR_FILTERS"
    });
    dispatch({type: "FETCH_DATA_PENDING" });
  };


useEffect(() => {
  if (doFetch) {
    loadData();
  }
}, [doFetch]);
```

Comment: No, this solution isn't suitable for use here, because I don't need to send a new request on every change in filters, only on Apply Filters button click or on Clear Filters button click or on select (by ckicking) a new page in pagination. It seems I need a some custom fetch data hook here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, `useEffect()` watches state in dependency lists but doesn't respond to events directly, you need to trigger the effects by setting a piece of state via `dispatch`. If the criteria is complicated, you can add another flag to state, but `filters` looks good enough to me!

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger effects manually using refs. This is often useful when using `useReducer` which cannot fire side effects.

```
 let fireFiltersClearEffect = React.useRef(false);

 const onFiltersClear = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CLEAR_FILTERS"
    });

    fireFiltersClearEffect.current = true;
  };

 React.useEffect(() => {
   if (fireFiltersClearEffect.current !== false) {
      loadData();
      fireFiltersClearEffect.current = false;
   }
  });
```

Comment: But filters are used in the request and this solution, in my mind, doesn't  guarantee that state will change correctly before request will be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to use thunk actions, these actions always have access to most recent state and can dispatch multiple actions. Thunk actions can even call other thunk actions and wait for them (if the thunk action **returns** a promise): `thunkAction(arg)(dispatch,getState).then(thunkActionResult=>otherStuff)`.

Thunks are well documented and easily recognized by other developers.

Thunk is a middleware of Redux but can be applied to useReducer with a custom hook:

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React;

const compose = (...fns) =>
  fns.reduce((result, fn) => (...args) =>
    fn(result(...args))
  );
const mw = () => (next) => (action) => next(action);
const createMiddleware = (...middlewareFunctions) => (
  store
) =>
  compose(
    ...middlewareFunctions
      .concat(mw)
      .reverse()
      .map((fn) => fn(store))
  );
const useMiddlewareReducer = (
  reducer,
  initialState,
  middleware = () => (b) => (c) => b(c)
) => {
  const stateContainer = useRef(initialState);
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const dispatch = (action) => {
    const next = (action) => {
      stateContainer.current = reducer(
        stateContainer.current,
        action
      );
      return setState(stateContainer.current);
    };
    const store = {
      dispatch,
      getState: () => stateContainer.current,
    };
    return middleware(store)(next)(action);
  };
  return [state, dispatch];
};

//middleware
const thunkMiddleWare = ({ getState, dispatch }) => (
  next
) => (action) =>
  typeof action === 'function'
    ? action(dispatch, getState)
    : next(action);
const logMiddleware = ({ getState }) => (next) => (
  action
) => {
  console.log('in log middleware', action, getState());
  Promise.resolve().then(() =>
    console.log('after action:', action.type, getState())
  );
  return next(action);
};

const init = { value: 'A' };
const TOGGLE = 'TOGGLE';
const later = () =>
  new Promise((r) => setTimeout(() => r(), 500));
const otherThunk = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'not relevant action form otherTunk' });
  console.log('in other thunk, state is:', getState());
  //note that I am returning a promise
  return later();
};
const thunkToggle = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  //dispatching other thunk and waiting for it to finish
  otherThunk()(dispatch, getState).then(() =>
    dispatch({ type: TOGGLE })
  );
};
const reducer = (state, { type }) => {
  console.log(`in reducer action type: ${type}`);
  //toggle state.value between A and B
  if (type === TOGGLE) {
    return { value: state.value === 'A' ? 'B' : 'A' };
  }
  return state;
};
const middleware = createMiddleware(
  thunkMiddleWare,
  logMiddleware
);
const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useMiddlewareReducer(
    reducer,
    init,
    middleware
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(thunkToggle())}>
        toggle
      </button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```